# Tweepy Error Python With Username Finding Top Tweet

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy

I'm making a program in Python, using Tweepy, that gets the top Tweet from a user, but for some reason it gives me am error when I try to run the program. Here is my code and my error I got.

```
import tweepy
consumer_key = ""
consumer_secret = ""
access_token = ""
access_token_secret = ""
auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)
api = tweepy.API(auth)
username='@username'
tweets_list= api.user_timeline(username, count=1)
tweet= tweets_list[0] 
print(tweet.created_at)
print(tweet.text)
print(tweet.in_reply_to_screen_name)
```

Here is my error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 10, in <module>
    tweets_list= api.user_timeline(username, count=1) # Get the last tweet
  File "/home/runner/elon-tweet/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tweepy/api.py", line 33, in wrapper
    return method(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/runner/elon-tweet/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tweepy/api.py", line 46, in wrapper
    return method(*args, **kwargs)
TypeError: user_timeline() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
```

Answer (score 1):

[`API.user_timeline`](https://tweepy.readthedocs.io/en/v4.6.0/api.html#tweepy.API.user_timeline) was changed in Tweepy v4.0.0 to no longer accept positional arguments.
The 1 positional argument being referred to in the error is self.
You probably want to pass `username` as the `screen_name` keyword argument instead.
See also [the relevant FAQ section in Tweepy's documentation about this](https://tweepy.readthedocs.io/en/v4.6.0/faq.html#why-am-i-getting-a-typeerror-about-an-api-method-taking-1-positional-argument-but-given-2).